# What are all the values that ColdFusion considers "falsy" and "truthy"?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm looking to compile a complete list of values that ColdFusion considers falsy and truthy.  The ones I know of are:

```
//falsy values
false
"false"
0
"no"

//truthy values
true
"true"
!= 0
"yes"
```

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: See this Luce ticket.  It's unimplemented right now, but may be for people finding this in the future: https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-449

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a neat little article on that here http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/2/5/Booleans.and.Coldfusion

but of course officially it's http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fd0.html

> In Boolean expressions, True, nonzero numbers, and the strings “Yes”, “1”, “True” are equivalent; and False, 0, and the strings “No”, “0”, and “False” are equivalent.
>
> Boolean evaluation is not case sensitive. For example, True, TRUE, and true are equivalent.

So, using your terminology:

```
//falsy values
False
"False"
0
"No"

//truthy values
True
"true"
!= 0
"Yes"
"1"
```

Comment: > 0 should be != 0 (all non-zero numbers are considered TRUE)