# What Integers Are Considered "true" in a ColdFusion "if" statement

Tags: coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the values that ColdFusion considers “falsy” and “truthy”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278528/what-are-all-the-values-that-coldfusion-considers-falsy-and-truthy)

In ColdFusion, what integers are considered `true` and what integers are considered `false` in an `if` statement? I know that `1` is `true` and `0` is `false`, but is this it?

For example, it would be nice to know that I can do an `if` on a query data structure's record count to determine if the query has at least one record in it. For example, let's say our query is called, `employees`.

```
<cfif variables.employees.recordCount>
    There ARE employees.
<cfelse>
    There ARE NO employees.
</cfif>
```

Would the statement "There ARE employees" be displayed if the record count was, say, 2?

Answer (score 12):

Any non zero number is true. Only 0 will return false.

Answer (score 5):

> The expression inside the cfif tag must evaluate to a Boolean value (a true/false). Boolean values are represented as either "true" or "false", "yes" or "no", or "0" or any number.
>
> [Reference](http://coldfusion.sys-con.com/node/44479)

So it looks like 0 is for false, or anything else for true in the case of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar question: 
[What are all the values that ColdFusion considers "falsy" and "truthy"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278528/what-are-all-the-values-that-coldfusion-considers-falsy-and-truthy)

Extensive blog post about how variables are evaluated for truthiness in ColdFusion: 
[What are all the values that ColdFusion considers "falsy" and "truthy"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278528/what-are-all-the-values-that-coldfusion-considers-falsy-and-truthy)